# Terminal is not recognizing commands

Tags: command-line

like cd/Documents gives "cd/Documents command not found " .The same thing with sudo command.
Not able to access an files, change directories or install software

Comment: Your command is wrong, it should be `cd ~/Documents`.

Comment: Still showing command not found

Comment: Which command have you used?

Comment: cd ~/Documents even cd ~/Desktop

Answer (score 1):

cd/Documents will not work. There should be a space after cd command and I think path you mentioned is incorrect, Document folder is in users home folder i.e. /home/{username}/Document in your case you can try

```
cd ~/Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

there should be space between a command and its argument. and present directory should also be noted. for you this one will work

```
cd Documents
```

First of all read this to know how to use terminal.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal